# How to remove group seperator from text file

Tags: debian, tr, control-characters, xxd

I have a text file that was created on a windows PC that I'm then opening on a debian machine. I open it in nano and at the bottom it says (Converted from DOS format).

When I grab a single line out of the file and look at it's binary representation using:

```
head -n1 filename.txt | xxd -b
```

It shows that two 00001101 characters have been added to the line. I'm trying to remove them with tr like this:

```
head -n1 filename.txt | tr -d "^]" | xxd -b
```

but that doesn't seem to be working.

Any idea how I can solve this issue? To create ^] I'm doing shift + ^ then ] do I need to do something else to generate the group separator control character?

Answer (score 0):

use `dos2unix` utility, there are a lot of `sed`/`perl`/`awk`/other solutions if you do a quick search. I would be surprised if this question is not answered a couple of times already on this site.